# Property of contractible spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two complex tori. Let $V$ and $V'$ be the tangent spaces at identity. Then the exponential map, which we denote by $\pi:V\longrightarrow X$ and $\pi':V'\longrightarrow Y$ are universal covering maps. Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic map. Then $f\circ\pi:V\longrightarrow Y$ is holomorphic. Why does this lift to a map $V\longrightarrow V'$? The reason given is that $V$ is contractible. But what property of a contractible space is being used here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need the "lifting lemma": Suppose that $p: X \to Y$ is a covering map, and let $f : Z \to Y$ be a continuous map. Pick points $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ so $x$ and $z$ are mapped to $y$ under these maps. If $f_{*} \pi_1(Z,z) \subset p_{*} \pi_1(X,x) \subset \pi_1(Y,y)$, then there is a unique lift $\tilde f: Z \to X$ so that $f(z) = x$ and so that the diagram commutes. (The converse is also true, but this is the nontrivial direction.)

So the property being used here is that a contractible space has trivial fundamental group, so such a lift always exists.